# Are released blocks logged in the journal for ext4?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, storage, journaling

Suppose we have a simple case:

- `ext4` file system with journaling
- a single file named `file`, which has no other hard links
- the `inode` for `file` has associated with it only 1 data `block`

My understanding of the deletion process for this specific case is as follows:

1. log that we will delete `file`

   1. log that we will reduce `inode`'s `ref_cnt` by 1
   2. commit
   3. log that because `ref_cnt` is 0, release `inode` back to pool
   4. commit
   5. log that because `inode` is released, release associated `block` back to pool
2. commit deletion of `file`

Among these, how do I get the block number that was released from step 1.5? Is it stored in the journal? If so, how would I access it?

I have been searching for some interface to the filesystem that gives this information. The best I've come to is `debugfs -R "logdump -a"`, but I'm not sure how to move forward from there.

NOTE: I understand that there are tools like `ext3grep` that will help me with recovering `file`. My goal is to try this manually by getting the block number out of the journal, for educational purposes. I also understand that the `inode` and `block` may be reused before getting this information. For the purposes of this question, assume that the filesystem is read-only after the delete is done.